# Add Badge when UITabBarController loads and not on the ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Maybe this is a simple question...

I have a UITabBarController with 3 Tab Bar Item that have 3 ViewController.

I am able to add Badge(by using setBadgeValue) to the Tab Bar Item but just on the ViewController but I want to add it when UITabBarController loads....

any idea?

thanks

Comment: The only condition is that this `tabBarItem` must exist when you're setting it's `badgaValue`.

Comment: is there anywhere I could find more information about this?

Comment: Well, tabBarItem is a property of viewController(s) so they'll at least have to bi initialized before you're trying to set badgeValues.

Comment: Documentation: [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457),[View Controller Catalog for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313),[UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it at `AppDelegate.m` after set tabBarController.

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1,vc2,vc3,vc4, nil];
NSArray *items = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items;
if (items && [items count]>2) {
    UITabBarItem *item = [items objectAtIndex:1];
    item.badgeValue = @"New";
}
```

Comment: Im not really sure where I do this

Answer (score 0):

You could add it to the desired UITabBarItem from the AppDelegate or anywhere else in the application.